# Best practice to send {ID} via GET Fetch

Tags: javascript

I have a user based app in which each user creates objects with specific IDs. When I fetch a list of these objects for each individual user i want to make sure the API only fetches the user's own objects. I tried realizing this in several ways, some of which are a bad idea (req.body in GET request), and others just don't work (put the ID by which mongoose searches in the headers => CORS doesn't like it; put the ID in `"data": JSON.stringify({userId})` just shows an empty `{}` when console logging `console.log(req.data)` on the backend)

I now added the userId in `params` and retrieve it on the backend via `req.params.id`, but I don't feel like that's very safe. What is a good way to solve this ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but is just a kind of recommendation: I prefer to keep this responsibilities on the backend side. for example your client app call to `/api/resource/1` and if the user has not access to this resource, the server should return an HTTP 403 error (just to say something). Remember that no mater what mechanism you use to "hide" the parameters, there is always a way to send a custom request to your API (using Postman or Fiddler)

Comment: I wouldn’t trust a userid coming from the client.  Rather it should be stored in the session on the web server.